# Disable userinteraction or touches event in UIView but still enable for subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have UIView like this.

[image]

I need to put my finger on that view and drag along on those button just like playing piano. Problem is that if initial touch point is on the main view and if I drag along, touches event for main view is triggered and my buttons touch events are not triggered.

As a result, I put this.

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Problem is that it has disabled my buttons and other subviews. I want to totally ignore touch event, user interaction from main view but allow for all those subview. How shall I do?

Comment: All subviews added on superview would not be clickable if you disable superview's user interaction. So if you want to make the keyboard view as clickable and main view as not clickable, then you must not add the key board on the main view, rather you can add it on window, then it will respond to click event even if you disable the user interaction of main view of that screen. Hope it helps...

Comment: But I can't add to window in keyboard extension. :(

Comment: Ok, then can you add other subviews that you need, in a separate View and disable that view's user interaction. I mean to say add a view and keyboard view to main view then add other stuffs to that view and disable that view's user interaction, The main concern is don't disable the superview's user interaction of keyboard view.

Comment: You can set up a notification event for `keyboardWillShow` and inside the target function set `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` for the superView and when `keyboardWillHide` notification re-enable it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Janmenjaya It is not okay. The moment when I disable particular UIView, all subview (for my case, it is button )in that view is disabled. Adding another subview is same as original plan though.

Comment: Yes it should be like that i already explained you. If you are going to disable a superview all of its subview will be disabled. So I told you to take two views one is for key board and another (lets say view1) is for other subviews if any. You wanted to make the keyboard enable, so I advised to add both the view (Keyboard view and the view1) in main view, so later when you disable view1, then along with view1 all of its subview will get disabled but keyboard view would be enable. What i understood is, you wanted to make few subviews disable so that ---
To be continued ....

Comment: while you slide over those subviews they will not touchable but when you come to keyboard view all your button would respond to touch as they are on keyboard view and keyboard view is on main view. And both main view and key board view's user interaction is true, only we have make it false for view1. That is what i understood from your question.

Comment: Let me digest first. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a notification event for `keyboardWillShow` and inside the target function set `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` for the superView and when `keyboardWillHide` notification re-enable it. For hiding the keyboard you could use the **GO** Button or to dismiss the keyboard add an invisible UIButton to the remaining part of the Screen when the `keyboardWillShow` event is called and use it to resign first responder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am doing custom keyboard. I think it is not valid,

Answer (score 0):

You should create a subclass of `UIView` for your main view. It should overwrite [`- hitTest:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc) returning always the nearest view for a key.

An alternative solution without inheritance is giving all keys an invisible border such that their views cover the complete main view but never returning the main view.